# Integrate iOS app with new Facebook Login

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, authentication

So I have Facebook login enabled on my app, and it's connecting to the app I set up on the developer portal on Facebook.  However, my team decided to create a universal Facebook app that we should all route our login through.  I changed the Facebook APP ID on my iOS app, changed the URL scheme, and yet when I run the app and try to login, it has me log in through my old app on Facebook.  I've been racking my brain trying to figure out how I can get it to connect with the new app.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have to grant permissions or do you login with no UI?

Comment: You have to change the Facebook app id in .plist also